# JasperReport Server REST 2 api - Repository servce does not give details on my created reports files

Tags: jasperserver

I am using JasperReports Server Rest v2 services, specifically the repository services, to find out all the reports hosted. I had created 2 reports inside a folder "Petrel" and those reports are working fine.

When I see the response of "rest_v2/resources" api I don't see the details about the newly created folder "Petrel" and also the details on 2 reports inside it.

And idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the above issue by using "rest/resources" which is actually the  previous version of the api and added 2 query variables

1. recursive = 1
2. type = reportUnit